# Merge rows in SQLite - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, merge, rows

I have an app that records expenses with the date & time using SQLite.
My table looks something like this:

```
__________________________________________
|   ID   |   Month  |   Day   |   Time   |
|________|__________|_________|__________|
|   1    |   JAN    |   19    |   2:00   |
|   2    |   JAN    |   21    |  12:50   |
|   3    |   JAN    |   21    |   1:35   |
|   4    |   FEB    |   09    |   4:10   |
|        |          |         |          |
|________|__________|_________|__________|
```

I want to make it so when another row is added with duplicate column information, it will merge with the previous row:

```
__________________________________________
|   ID   |   Month  |   Day   |   Time   |
|________|__________|_________|__________|
|   1    |   JAN    |   19    |   9:00   |
|        |          |   21    |  12:50   |
|        |          |         |   1:35   |
|   2    |   FEB    |   09    |   4:10   |
|        |          |         |          |
|________|__________|_________|__________|
```

Can anyone help me with this??
I know how to create and update tables, I'm only looking for a way to merge rows together so it shows up easily in a listview! 
-Thanks

Comment: Database store one information in one cell. You want to store multiple values in one row?

Comment: What you are asking for can't be done.  Each row in the database is independent.  So forget changing the database to solve your problem.. The answer will be in how you form your SQL query and setup your adapter logic.  Describing what end result you want will help people answer your REAL question.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you mean by merging.... you are going to loose the information related to day and time if you merge by months.... and if you have other tables depending on that ID, you will need to modify those first.

But as far as merging itself, look into the SQL command 'GROUP BY'

If what you want to do is just change what is displayed, then do not change anything in the database... just write some code that compares what you want to display compared to what was in the previous row.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to make it so when another row is added with duplicate column
>   information, it will merge with the previous row

You cannot do this on the update/insert side. You have to manage this on the query side. An insight into what your listview looks like would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking for is normalizing your database. For storing the information like you describe it, you would use three tables and connect them with foreign keys.

One for month:

```
_____________________
|   ID   |   Month  |
|________|__________|
|   1    |   JAN    |
|   2    |   FEB    |
|________|__________|
```

Another one for days:

```
__________________________________
|   ID   |   Month_ID  |   Day   |
|________|_____________|_________|
|   1    |      1      |   19    |
|   2    |      1      |   21    |
|   3    |      2      |   09    |
|________|_____________|_________|
```

And yet another for the time:

```
___________________________________
|   ID   |   Day_ID    |   Time   |
|________|_____________|__________|
|   1    |      1      |   2:00   |
|   2    |      2      |  12:50   |
|   3    |      2      |   1:35   |
|   4    |      3      |   4:10   |
|________|_____________|__________|
```

This way your Database has neither redundancy nor null-values. Migrating from your DB to this layout can be quiet an obstacle but maybe worth the effort.

Further reading: [Wikipedia on Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)